# How to write a SQL command in C# EF Core with a condition in the join clause

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework-core

I am trying to translate the following SQL command in a C# EF Core query.

```
SELECT u.firstname, c.name FROM notification AS n 
LEFT JOIN user AS u ON n.objectID=u.userID AND n.notificationType=0
LEFT JOIN conversation c ON n.objectID=c.conversationID AND n.notificationType=1;
```

So essentially, I have 3 tables. The *user* and *conversation* tables contains information about a user and a conversation. The *notification* table contains the field *notificationType* that tells which kind of notification it is : 0 for a *user* notification and 1 for a *conversation* notification. The field *objectID*, in the notification table, contains an id. The id in this field depends on the value in *notificationType*. If the value is 0, the id is a user id. If the value is 1, the id is a conversation id. So depending on the value of *notificationType* I want to join on a different table. I am currently able to do all the command, except adding the AND in the ON clause of each JOIN command...

The idea of this design is to reduce the amount of column that the *notification* table will have. In the future, there will be more notification type. So how can I translate the SQL request in an EF Core function call? Maybe also this design is bad. I am very open to any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: You compose anonymously typed objects and do an `equals` join between them. Take a look at https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/linq/linq-inner-join-with-and-and-or-condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use generics in a table-per-heirachy. That way you can generate the correct joins, just using navigation properties.

```cs
public abstract class Notification{
    public int NotificationType { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
public class Notification<T> where T:class{
    public T Parent { get; set; }
}
public class User {
    public virtual ICollection<Notification<User>> Notification { get; set; }
}
public class Conversation {
    public virtual ICollection<Notification<Conversation>> Notification { get; set; }
}

// OnModelCreating

modelBuilder.Entity<Notification>()
    .HasDiscriminator(n => n.NotificationType)
        .HasValue<Notification<User>>(0)
        .HasValue<Notification<Conversation>>(1);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Notification)
    .WithOne(n => n.Parent)
    .HasForeignKey(n => n.ParentId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Conversation>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Notification)
    .WithOne(n => n.Parent)
    .HasForeignKey(n => n.ParentId);
```

Though an EF Core migration might try to create invalid foreign keys. How you represent the relationship in the database is a separate issue.

You could also introduce a curiously recursive interface. To ensure everything is configured correctly.

```cs
public interface IHaveNotifications<T> where T:class,IHaveNotifications<T>{
    int Id { get; set; }
    ICollection<Notification<T>> Notification { get; set; }
}
```

But I'll leave the rest of the implementation as an exercise for the reader.