# EF Core and referencing the ID of a entity before calling SaveChangesAsync()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a scenario where I want to add an entity (say EntityA), but I also want to add details of this entity, including the auto-generated ID, to an Outbox entity, before calling SaveChanges().  This is so I can have both inserts wrapped within the same transaction.

The Outbox entity has a field called `AggregateId` and is of type `string`.

The auto-generated ID field of EntityA is of type `long`.

Basically every time I insert/update EntityA (or EntityB, EntityC, etc), I want to also add an Outbox entity.

What I can't work out is, how to do this so that when both EntityA, and the Outbox entity are saved, the AggregateId is populated with the newly generated ID of EntityA.

```cs
var entityA = new EntityA()
{
   // public long Id { get; set; }  //-- Auto-generated
   // set other properties ...
};
_context.Entities.Add(entityA);

var outbox = new Outbox()
{
   AggregateType = nameof(EntityA),
   AggregateId = entityA.Id.ToString()
};
_context.Outboxes.Add(outbox);

// I even tried ...
// outbox.AggregateId = entityA.Id.ToString();

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I don't think it is a foreign key set up I'm after because AggregateId could refer to EntityA, EntityB, etc, but I could be wrong.

Is there a way to set up a one-way relationship in EF Core so that EntityA refers to a `ICollection<Outbox> Outboxes` but maps the Id(`long`) to AggregateId(`string`), therefore allowing me to do ...

```cs
entityA.Outboxes.Add(outbox);
```

Comment: This is what navigation properties are for. Don't try to initialise the Id, instead assign the navigation property. Your `Outbox` type could be implemented as a table-per-heirachy, so it can have multiple types of navigations. eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/69356696/4139809

Comment: @JeremyLakeman ... But how do I set up a navigation property so that Id (long) maps to AggregateId (string)?

Comment: Again, you don't. Navigations require that the FK columns have the same types as the PK columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from @jeremy-lakeman was the answer to this problem (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69356696/4139809).

But I did need to add another field to my outbox entity, that was the same type as the entity Id.  I couldn't get it to work when the Id of my entity was, say, a `long`, and the foreign key field was a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

If you construct the backing class correctly then everything works. You do not need any Id property. EF itself constructs the correct `int EntityAId` foreign key relationship

```
public class EntityA
{
    ...
    public ICollection<EntityB> SetOfBs { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    ...
    public EntityB EntityA { get; set; }
}


var a = new EntityA();
var b = new EntityB() { EntityA = a };

context.Bs.Add(a)
context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work because I don't/can't have a reference from EntityB to EntityA since EntityB could actually reference EntityA, EntityC, etc.  I'm hoping to be able to do it without navigation.  But I'm starting to think this is not possible.

Comment: If you do not need the reference in B then you can let the ICollection and add B to the SetOfBs in A. But then you possibly might configure the FK using fluent API