# Entity Framework Include or Select based on Column Value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'd like to do something like a conditional include or select based on the value of a column in my parent table.

Parent table:

```
Guid Id  
nvarchar(50) Name  
int Type  
Guid ObjectId
```

Child 1

```
Guid Id  
nvarchar(50) Name
```

Child 2

```
Guid Id  
nvarchar(50) Name
```

When I populate my model, I need to do a condition based on what type id is in the parent table.

For example

- If the row Type == 1, then the include / select needs to be done on Child 1 for Id and Name.
- If the type == 2 then from Child 2.

You would of course not be able to do a normal include, so would a select be the better option here? How would I go about it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF: Include with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798796/ef-include-with-where-clause)

Comment: By using generics in a TPH? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69356696/4139809